# Connecting Github to VS Code on MacBook Pro

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, connection, ssh-keys

I'm want to connect my github account to vs code and have tried various things.
I made sure the email I added in my terminal was the same one in my account settings.
I've tried adding an ssh key (which I might've done wrong since I'd never done that before).
I added the Gitlens extension, logged into my account, then deactivated and reactivated git in vs code.

I created a repository in vs code and made two commits. Everything shows up in vs (except that my commits don't show up in the timeline).
I tried opening a repository I created on github in vs code and that didn't work either.

How do I get the two to communicate together?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating commits on VSCode has no bearing on a remote GitHub repository.

You would need to [push them ("Sync")](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71827949/6309) in order for them to be published.

What you should do is:

- make sure your SSH key is recognized: `ssh -Tv git@github.com`
- make sure you have created an empty repository on GitHub
- go to your local repository folder
- type `git remote add origin git@github.com:Me/MyNewProject`
  (Replace "`Me`" with your GitHub user account name, and `MyNewProject` with a more meaningful name)
- go back to VSCode, and click on the "Sync" button

You should see your commits on GitHub.

Comment: @redfox Great, well done! With IDEs using Git, it is generally helpful to fall back temporarily to the command-line whenever there is an issue. Once it is working from command-line, chances are it works better in the IDE.